# Validations on money-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, money-rails

I have money-rails gem installed and it's working flawlessly. However, there are no validations on money objects when I create a new model record. If I try to input letters into the money field, the form submission is successful, it just sets the value to 0. How do I get those validations working? I have no code for the actual validation, seeing as money-rails on github states that it has validations included, but I have tried `validates_numericality_of` to no avail.

**EDIT**
Yes I have read the docs extensively, and tried the validation option suggested on Github.

Comment: [Docs](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#numericality-validation-options) validation options

Comment: create your custom validation.

Answer (score 3):

I have this example hope it could help you

```
monetize  :price_cents, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0, :less_than => 10}

validates :price, :format => { :with => /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }
```

just like this one of them (monetize validation) will validate the numericality stuff and the other one will validate the format.

Comment: your second line works, but I do have a side-note: after giving an error and not persisting to the db, in an edit action, the render 'edit' renders the form with a new rounded value. I'd like it beter if say 12,5056, re-renders to 12,50 rather than 12,51.

Comment: Remember to add the column on DB with the '_cents' suffix instead 'price' will be 'price_cents' and add attr_accessor for price.

`attr_accessor :price`

About the rounded values, you should work in a method or check the documentation, not sure if there is something for it.